# FFT implementation with decimation in frequency vs decimation in time?

Tags: fft

When using FFT implementations which would be the advantages of using decimation in time (DIT) vs decimation in frequency(DIF) and vise-versa?

I have read [here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-decimation-in-time-and-decimation-in-frequency) that in practice there is not much difference between DIT and DIF FFTs, but the hardware of some DSPs (Digital Signal Processors) is optimized for certain FFT variants. I would like to have more information about this if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that article equates "FFT" with "Radix-2 FFT", which isn't really true.

Anyway, since both decimation in frequency and decimation in time need exactly the same components running at the same speeds, the only difference I'd expect for radix-2 FFTs would be if you can have a parallel input on one side, and serial output on the other (or vice-versa); in that case, you could do the "large" butterfly on the side where you need to have the data in parallel to avoid latency, and could save on components by re-using a smaller butterfly for the serial end without much of a downside. Whether you want that or not *very* much depends on space, power, latency and throughput constraints.

For mixed-radix FFTs, where you're not only dealing with a single prime factor in the FFT size, you might not have the freedom to rearrange these layers.